# Reading data from CSV file. Convert data into an array

Tags: java, csv, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get a project finished but am having no luck. It is an online course so my only communication is through email. He has yet to reply to my four emails over the last five days.

So for this assignment we had to download a csv file from containing NASDAQ stock price info for a specific company. I chose GOOG (google). Below are the requirements for the code portion.

Create a second file ReadFiles.java. This is the file that will read in the data from your csv file. Note: You will want to use a smaller version of your data file (20 rows) for testing. 
Your ReadFiles.java class requires the following methods:

Method: check to see if the file exists

Method: find number of rows in csv file

Method: Converts the csv file to a mutli-dimensional array

Method: PrintArray

Method: Return array using a get method

Create a file DataAnalyzer.java. This file will be used to call the methods in ReadFiles.java. Be sure to demonstrate that all of your methods work through DataAnalyzer.java.

This is what I have so far.

```
package Analysis;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadFiles 
{
    public static int numberOfRows;
    public static int rowNumber = 0;
    public static int columnNumber = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
        String fileName;
        System.out.print("Enter the file name >> ");
        fileName = kb.nextLine();
        File f = new File("D:\\Java\\Assignment 3\\" + fileName);
        if(f.exists())
        {
            System.out.print("File exists.");
        }
        fileName="D:\\Java\\Assignment 3\\" + fileName;
        try 
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            StringTokenizer st = null;

            while((fileName = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                rowNumber++;
                numberOfRows++;

                st = new StringTokenizer(fileName, ",");

                while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                {
                        columnNumber++;
                        System.out.println("Row " + rowNumber + 
                                    ", Column " + columnNumber 
                                + ", Entry : "+ st.nextToken());
                }
                columnNumber = 0;
            }
        }       
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void rows()
    {
        System.out.println("Total Rows: " + numberOfRows);
    }
}
```

The book we have been given for the course is no help. All of the "Examples" and "You do it" portions give errors. Also in the entire chapter this assignment is based on, not one mention of an array.

When I run this code I do not get any error. I am shown the following:

```
File exists.
Row 1, Column 1, Entry : 30/12/2011
Row 1, Column 2, Entry : 642.02
Row 1, Column 3, Entry : 646.76
Row 1, Column 4, Entry : 642.02
Row 1, Column 5, Entry : 645.9
Row 1, Column 6, Entry : 1782300
Row 1, Column 7, Entry : 645.9
Row 2, Column 1, Entry : 29/12/2011
Row 2, Column 2, Entry : 641.49
```

I am shown from row 1 - 19 (the entire file).

What I do not understand is how to create separate methods in this class to convert to an array, print the array, and return the array.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It seems to me you need to go through few of Java programming basics: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/, the question is too broad for StackOverflow

Comment: look at openCSV http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ great for csv files

Answer (score 0):

You need to define 2 classes, DataAnalyzer and ReadFiles. You usually have one file per class, although this is not a requirement. The structure of ReadFiles has been provided, so you will have a file called ReadFiles.java like this:

```
public class ReadFiles{

    //instance var(s)
    ...

    //constructor(s)
    ...

    //methods(s)

    /**
      * Checks whether the file exists
     */
    public boolean exists(){
        ....
    }

    /*
     * Number of rows in the file
     */
    public int getRowCount(){
        ....
    }

    // add the rest your self!!
}
```

}

You'll also need a file called DataAnalyzer.java:

```
public class DataAnalyzer{

    public static void main(String args){
        //create ReadFiles and call it's methods and check they return what is expected
    }

}
```

Assume the ReadFile manages a single input file; it probably needs a class variable to hold that information. The DataAnalyzer will need to tell the ReadFiles which file to analyse (a constructor seems a good choice).

My advice is to create your skeleton structure (you already have been told what it is) and start building the functionality of each method one at a time.